# gitでのバージョン管理での「？」

Tags: xcode, git, xcode7

Gitでバージョン管理を行おうとした際にファイルすべての横のマークが「？」になってしまいました。

バージョン管理する際に必要なファイルと管理しなくても良いファイルを教えて下さい。
CocoaPodsも入れています。

Comment: 「git init」後、「git add .」ですべてのファイルを追加すると、何かしら問題が起きる可能性がありますでしょうか。

Comment: 1. i) バージョン管理を「行おうとした」で何をしたのか， ii) 「横のマーク」って何か（これは似た環境で使っておられる方なら説明不要なのかもしれないですが） あたりがわからなくてお助けできません．なにかしらそのへんを具体化出来ないでしょうか．

Comment: 2. バージョン管理する際に必要なファイルと不要なファイルはそれこそケースバイケースですから，一般には必要なファイルは必要，としか言えないとおもいます．またこれは多分前半と関係が薄いので，質問するなら別の質問に分けたほうがよいのではないかと思います．言語ごとの典型的な .gitignore とかは [github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore) が参考になるかもしれません．

Comment: 3. `git init` した後 `git add .` しただけでは基本的には問題は起きないと思います．すべてのファイルを追加したいわけでないなら当然問題ですが，それでも望みの状態に持っていくのに数ステップ余分にかかる程度でしょう．

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[このリポジトリ](https://github.com/github/gitignore)にそれぞれの言語、プロジェクトで作成するべき`.gitignore`が一覧されているのでこれを使って必要であれば追加していくのがいいと思います。
また、[gibo](https://github.com/simonwhitaker/gibo)というシェルスクリプトを使うと、コマンドで`.gitignore`を生成できるので便利です。